# Campo de senha via ajax no Dajngo

Tags: django

Olá, quero preencher o campo password do meu model Company em enviando o valor digitado via post ajax, vi que existe o widget PasswordInput quando se utiliza modelform porém não queria utilizar modelform e sim via ajax, é obrigatório utilizar modelform para salvar senhas?

Meu model:

```
from django.db import models

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField( max_length=254, blank=False, null=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
```

Comment: Não, não é obrigado, não importa de onde a informação venha, na sua view vc pode processa-la da forma como for necessario e salva-la no banco.

Answer (score 0):

Dica: você pode fazer hash de password dentro da sua view, e salvar no Field que você desejar.

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password

hashed_pwd = make_password("plain_text")
check_password("plain_text",hashed_pwd)
```